# ID hashing vs encryption on public pages

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash

*I've read a number of SO posts on this subject, but they seem to shrug it off as unimportant, so maybe if I give you my real world example that will affect the answer.*

A system that manages contact lists and sends out emails, but allows the recipients to **unsubscribe** using a unique url.

Since this is a public page, it would be trivial for someone to just increment the ids and unsubscribe other users aswell.

I don't want to add a unique hash that I'd have to store in the database for each combination of user/contact/list.

What's the best approach to this? Are one of the following acceptable?

a) encrypt all the IDs and decrypt serverside

b) include a hash in the url based on the 3 IDs and a salt, and then confirm it server-side

Comment: I believe your best approach here is a randomly generated identifier for each user.

Comment: i do do what you say you dont want to do, that is store a unique hash for each user, for just this kind of thing

Comment: @Adnan that would work, but I'm trying to avoid that, since that's something I'd need to store in the database. Call it my last resort here.

Comment: You don't have to store the tokens in advance, they can be created when an unsubscribe request is received.

Comment: @Dagon I do that for my users, but since each of my users can have 1000-50000 contacts, that would get really big, really fast.

Comment: you have so little space you cant store a hash with a user?  1000-50000  is not many, i have millions

Comment: @Thilo how would that work? I imagine I'd have to generate the token when the email is being sent.

Comment: 1) receive unsubscribe request. 2) generate token, send confirmation email 3) receive token back within a few hours, then unsubscribe

Comment: IMHO people don't want to have to do things to unsub, you are making it to hard with additional email confirmation.

Comment: Oh I see. But that adds an extra step for the user, and the standard way to let contacts unsubscribe is by using a single link, so that won't do. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: You need to have some sort of authentication. Either email confirmation, or login to your website. It cannot be just a link with information that can be guessed or stolen.

Comment: @Dagon you're probably right, I should just store the hash it seems. I'll wait for more answers first. I was hoping for a different solution, but if it's the best one, then no reason not to go with it. (add it as an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question and comments, your requirements are

- allow the user to unsubscribe with 1 click on a link
- don't store any individual tokens in your database

You are going to have an action on your server triggered by a http GET request, like

```
http://youremailsystem.tl/unsubscribe&user=12&contact=34&list=56
```

While your suggestion 1), encryption, adds the additional benefit of privacy (the URL does not give away what action with which parameters is performed), number 2) is the simpler approach.

You [should use a MAC function to sign your URL parameters](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2012/06/09/why-you-should-never-use-hash-functions-for-message-authentication/). The input will be your parameters that you want to sign plus a secret key, that never leaves your server.

```
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $url, $mysecretkey);
$url = $url . '&signature=' . $signature;
```

Which makes the signature part of the unsubscribe URL in your email.

```
http://youremailsystem.tl/unsubscribe&user=12&contact=34&list=56&signature=b1812e463a7
```

Whenever a GET request comes in, you can verify that the parameters have not been changed.

Rough code:

```
// extract sent signature from url:
$sent_signature = //substr($sent_url ...

// strip signature from URL:
$sent_url = //substr($sent_url ...

// repeat hashing:
$correct_signature = $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $sent_url, $mysecretkey);

if( $sent_signature == $correct_signature ) {
    // do the unsubscribe
}
```

Note that any URL can be called repeatedly, so make sure you never re-use any of your IDs, or else you would enable an ex-user to unsubscribe a newer user much later that now has their ID.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. What are the chances of a hacker cracking the secret key based on multiple signature examples?

Comment: +1. A HMAC with a suitable hash function (such as SHA-256 here) and a suitably complex secret key is not practically crackable given any quantity of signed material. Much prefer this to storing multiple per-user secrets in the DB.

Comment: The article by James Coglan linked in my answer talks quite a bit about possible attacks on hashes. In this case, an attacker would have to brute-force the secret key. It wouldn't matter whether they have one example or multiple. If the key is good, you're fine.

Comment: I would add a 8 byte random salt before hashing to remove replay attacks (include it in the URL), and I would make sure not to reuse any user or list identifiers. You could use url-safe base64 to shorten the URL somewhat.

Comment: Good point about the re-used IDs, I added it to the answer. Could you elaborate on how an additional salt would prevent replays? The signature would still be valid on a repeated call of the URL, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

My view as someone who spent several years writing newsletter software (SAAS).

create a hash for each user\joiner\member sans store it with there other details. use that in a link for un-subscription.

I always had 2 hashes in my link, one was the newsletter sending hash, then you can track which one they unsubscribed from, as well as the per personal hash.

If you do want to expire the unsub link after a certain amount of time, as suggested by Thilo, you can use the date the newsletter was sent as determined by the, newsletter sending hash, but you will want to give them an alternative method, if the link is deemed to old. Such as another email

obligatory piece of code.

```
$hash = md5(uniqid(true));
```

store in db field with unique index. If you prefer you could add the email address in the mix to but uniqid() is designed to be, well, unique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This looks like the way to go, now that I have weighed in my options. And since you have the experience in the field I'm using this, that's just all the more reason to go by your answer.

Comment: @pixelistik completely true, don't know that i was thinking, i have removed "random" from the answer.

Comment: I think you should have rather removed the term "hash". `md5(uniqid(true));` *is* random. Which is good, if you store that token for later comparison with whatever the client presents. If the tokens in the URL were md5 hashes of the User and List ID, it would be trivial to fake requests.

Comment: "md5 — Calculate the md5 hash of a string" so it is hash, what ever else it may also be.

Answer (score 1):

Why the reluctance to create an unique token for each user?
You DON'T have to create it for each combination you describe (user/contact/list), but just for the user you associate with an emailaddress.

Then use that single token for each action. And change it after it is used. Just generated 20 random numbers of something. It is easy and safe.

Comment: But here is the thing, if I'm using tokens based on the user (and not the contacts) then the token is found out on that send, and a hacker can effectively unsubscribe all the contacts that got that one email. Since the email stays in the contacts inbox, the token has to stay valid too.

Comment: I might just end up storing a unique token for each recipient it seems.

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow your first comment, but to your second one: Yes: A token per recipient (email).

Answer (score 0):

All mailing lists I have every used sent me a confirmation mail to unsubscribe with a presumably random and unique token in there that expires after a few hours.

> I don't want to add a unique hash that I'd have to store in the database for each combination of user/contact/list.

You don't have to create them in advance or store them indefinitely. You can create random tokens when your receive an unsubscribe request, and delete it when done or expired.

Comment: i don't like the expire idea, i may come back in a week or month and use a link on an old email to unsub

Comment: When an expired token is used, then you get mailed a new token. The point is that you need to prove you have control over that email address at the time.

Comment: still, personally, don't like it as a user, so don't do it as a developer.

Comment: Also, if the links don't expire, and you accidentally forward the email or send someone the HTML for your page, you are in trouble.

Comment: being unsubscribed by another in this case is probably not going to be the end of the world.

Comment: @Dagon, stop posting awesome comments! I can't just keep upvoting them all.

Comment: @Thile the forwarding issue is an open issue for the big email players too. They seem to ignore it.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure who those big players are, but the lists I have used always send you a token that expires in a mail that only deals with unsubscribing. The normal mails (that you might want to share with other people) do not include any such tokens (just the public link to get the token).

Answer (score 0):

Use the email address along with user id (for possible duplicate addresses in your list(s)) in your hash for each user. store the hash along with the address in the db.

This way it is hard to reproduce the hash if you do not know the other users email.

Comment: And trivial to reproduce if you do know the other's email address. Completely random tokens that expire are best. Cannot be guessed (because they are random), cannot be stolen (because they expire).

Comment: You need to know the other´s email in combination with each email´s user id. That would be a real tricky one. :)

Comment: @Henkealg, nothing is a _real tricky one_ for a determined attacker. An attacker who wants to unsubscribe the site's whole user base.

Comment: And user's email address and user names are not hard to find out. At least use some secret information in your hash.

Comment: I like the idea since it is tricky to get the right combination of hash/email/id, but it can be cracked with a brute force attack, and what @Adnan said is a possibility.

Comment: @Adnan, add a microtime stamp to the hash as well. That should get leave the hacker working for a while. I am not that keen on randoms as they always have a small risk of generating duplicates, even in a system with expiring tokens.